# Adding large numbers on python with an algorithm, not with standard calculating

Tags: python, algorithm

My teacher gave me a homework to do a python program that adds large numbers and uses standard algorithm of adding. (I know that Python 3.x itself can add large numbers, but I need the way of adding)

Here is an example of standard algorithm: [How to Add Large Numbers Using Column Addition](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihpJXEscLKAhWFfywKHd2HDVQQFggeMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dummies.com%2Fhow-to%2Fcontent%2Fhow-to-add-large-numbers-using-column-addition.html&usg=AFQjCNGP4CqQlIg8mxzdt7GTXUYSRQTMSg&bvm=bv.112454388,d.bGg)

I have tried to do a program but, I could not do it.
I did not find any answers that satisfies me from StackOverflow.
Here is my buggy and not complete try that can only add numbers with equal rooms (e.g. 12 and 45, 444 and 765, not 1 and 134).

```
n=str(raw_input("n:"))
m=str(raw_input("m:"))
k=0
res=''
if m>n:
    m,n=n,m
k=0
for i in range(len(n)-1,-1,-1):
    a=float(n[i])
    try:
        b=float(m[i])
    except:
        b=float(0)
    k=float(k)
    res+=str(int((a+b+k)%10))
    if a+b+k>9:
        k=1
    else:
        k=0
print(res[::-1])
```

P.S. I am beginner in Python, and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In python, a swap can simply be written as `a,b=b,a`. Just FYI.

Comment: What is the problem with your program? Do you get an error or the wrong answer? Either way, what is it?

Comment: Also, why are you using float - is you program expected to handle user inputs like "1.23"?

Comment: I want to add floats too. In python it shows like 3.6e+13, not 36 111 111 111 111.25. And my program is meant for calculating large numbers like 555555555555555555555 + 4444444444444444444444 without using python's standard way.

Comment: Floating point numbers won't help you with that, due to the way they are stored - they are not a magic bullet to storing large numbers (and if they were, couldn't you just do `float(m) + float(n)`?)

Comment: I want to  `float(m) + float(n)` result very precise calculation.

Comment: OK. I think what you should do is to convert each digit as you calculate it to a string, that way you never need to actually store a large number in python (

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101513/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-olimjon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append zeroes to the beginning of `m` and your code will work normally also since you are adding integer you should use `int()` not `float()`
and you need after the for loop to add the carry to the result check this code

```
n=raw_input("n:")
m=raw_input("m:")
k=0
res=''
if len(m)>len(n):
    n,m = m,n #this will swap
k=0
m = "0" * (len(n)-len(m)) + m #append zeroes to m at the begining
for i in range(len(n)-1,-1,-1):
    a=int(n[i])
    b = int(m[i])
    k=int(k)
    res+=str(int((a+b+k)%10))
    if a+b+k>9:
        k=1
    else:
        k=0

#add the remainder
if (k !=0) :
    res += str(k)

print(res[::-1])
```

Comment: Can it be used to calculate floats? It shows an error on them

Comment: yes but the logic will be different think of a float as two numbers you are adding and place the . after you are done calculating also the carry in the . case shouldnot be appended to result but used in adding the digits before the sign the original code won't work for floats as its

Comment: OK, I will try that myself. Thanks for the answer again.

Comment: this don't work perfectly, it fail in 9+18 for example. also there is no need for str(raw_input(...)) because raw_input is a string already

Answer (score 1):

Python has the `izip_longest`-function, to fill up missing `0`s:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
n = raw_input("n:")
m = raw_input("m:")
k = 0
res = ''
for a, b in izip_longest(reversed(n), reversed(m), fillvalue='0'):
    k, z = divmod(int(a)+int(b)+k, 10)
    res = str(z) + res
if k:
    res = str(k) + res
print res
```